# How to distribute pandas dataframe operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am trying to parallelize dataframe operations for faster performance using a Dask cluster with a 6GB RAM limit per node. Here is the code I am using.

First I am using pandas as a baseline.

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

def print_cnt(df):
    print(len(df))

# 170MB parquet, 13 Million Records
df = pd.read_parquet('trip-data.parquet', engine='pyarrow')

print_cnt(df[df.tip_amount == 0])
print_cnt(df[df.payment_type == 1])
print_cnt(df[df.trip_distance > 10])

# 5717616
# 7834821
# 724979
# Wall time: 4.92 s
```

```py
df.info(memory_usage='deep')
# dtypes: ...
# memory usage: 2.9 GB
```

So far, so good. Now I am trying to parallelize the pandas operation using Dask:

```py
def evaluate(df, condition):
    return len(df[condition])

cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=4, memory_limit='4GB')
client = Client(cluster)

futures = [
    client.submit(evaluate, df, df.tip_amount == 0),
    client.submit(evaluate, df, df.payment_type == 1),
    client.submit(evaluate, df, df.trip_distance > 10)
]
res = [fut.result() for fut in futures]
```

This ends up hanging for a long time and never finishes.

Finally I try using dask dataframes instead:

```py
# 170MB parquet, 13 Million Records
ddf = dd.read_parquet('trip-data.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
ddf = ddf.repartition(npartitions=8)

print_cnt(ddf[ddf.tip_amount == 0])
print_cnt(ddf[ddf.payment_type == 1])
print_cnt(ddf[ddf.trip_distance > 10])
```

but I end up getting this message:

```
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting
distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker
```

```py
ddf.info(memory_usage='deep')
# dtypes: ...
# memory usage: 1.9 GB
```

How can I successfully parallelized these operations?

Comment: How many partitions in trip-data.parquet, and what is the in-memory size of the dataframe?

Comment: @mdurant I have edited the question to answer your questions. I have repartition the dataframe to 8 parts.

Comment: Yes, but how many partitions ("row-groups") in the original file?

Comment: When I used read_parquet on the file, and then called `ddf.npartitions` and `ddf.divisions`  before doing repartition, I always get 1 partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original data is made of exactly one native row-group. Dask cannot load this into separate partitions, so when you "repartition", it loads everything into one worker and only then splits off the pieces. This means that the whole 2.9GB dataset, plus temporary intermediates (e.g., for serialization), must fit within the 4GB limit you have set for workers. As you see, this doesn't work for you. Usually, we recommend having at least double the in-memory data size available, which in this case happens to be true for the whole machine, but not for workers.

You have a couple of clear possibilities from here:

- use the "threaded" scheduler instead of distributed for dask. This makes fewer copies of data.
- repartition your data using pandas alone and save back to parquet with multiple row-groups/files for later parallel operations
- use pandas alone and don't worry about dask. In fact, this is the [standard advice](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html#use-pandas) in the dask docs for when your data fits into memory on one node.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant for your detailed response. I ended up using pandas to load the file and then re-save it using a fix-length chunksize. The new file now has multiple partitions and a metadata file. Going forward, I will use a pandas whenever the DF can comfortably fit in a DF and use dask otherwise.